# Issue in returning plain json object from mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function that finds one object inside my schema database. If I console.log it, it displays correctly. But outside the function when I use it or console log it, It returns a null object. Please help

My function:

```
var pushQues = function(quesObj){ 
var query = {AnswerId: 'Texas'};
Question.findOne(query).lean().exec(function(err,docs){
    console.log(docs.Ques);
    console.log(docs);
    quesObj = docs;
});};
```

Console(Returns Correctly):

```
Which is the biggest state?
{ _id: 5815366d49fd95ec160728d8,
 Ques: 'Which is the best language?',
 Answers: [ 'Texas', 'Georgia', 'New york', 'Ohio' ],
 AnswerId: 'Texas' }
```

Trying to retrieve quesObj from outside function:

```
var quesObj={};
pushQues(quesObj);
console.log('and quesobj here: '+ quesObj);
console.log('question here: '+ quesObj.Ques);
```

console(Doesnt work):

```
 and quesob here: [object Object]
 quesob here: undefined
```

Comment: Can you print your first console with stringify and check the value is coming or not `console.log(JSON.stringify(quesObj))`?

Comment: as you are overriding it and then assign it which is obviously getting undefined

Comment: Using stringify I got back an undefined

Comment: Well I have to initialize it before I can modify it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the issue of async nature try to pass the `callback` to get it.

```
var pushQues = function(quesObj, callback) {
  var query = {
    AnswerId: 'Texas'
  };
  Question.findOne(query).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs.Ques);
    console.log(docs);
    callback(null, docs);
  });
};


pushQues(quesObj,function(err,result){
console.log('and quesobj here: '+ result);
console.log('question here: '+ result.Ques);  
});
```

**Update**

```
var async = require('async');
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    var pushQues = function(quesObj, callback) {
      var query = {
        AnswerId: 'Texas'
      };
      Question.findOne(query).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs.Ques);
        console.log(docs);
        callback(err, docs);
      });
    };
  }
], function(err, result) {
if(!err){
  console.log(result);
}
});
```

Comment: This work, but only from within the call back, Is there anyway to set an object outside to result?

Comment: Yes, you can use promise or async module to get it

Comment: Okay I will research that a little more and let you know what happens

Comment: use waterfall method of async module. see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you sooo much You all made me realize that I need to learn async a little better. Can't tell you how many hours I put into this problem :)

Comment: Cool it happens Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want this  **pushQues function** declaration as it is an issue of async

```
var pushQues = function(quesObj, callback){ 
var query = {AnswerId: 'Texas'};
var quesObj = {} ;
return Question.findOne(query).lean().exec(function(err,docs){
    console.log(docs);
    quesObj = docs;
    callback(null, docs);
});};
```

calling **pushQues Function**

```
pushQues(quesObj,function(err,result){
console.log('and quesobj here: '+ result);
console.log('question here: '+ result.Ques);
```

Comment: That's still sending back a null and undefined

Comment: what is an output og `console` that is used in `pushQues funtion`

Comment: It returns [object Object]

Comment: make `return` in `Question.findOne` then when you calling pushQues after console RESULT what is ?

Comment: Inside the function if returns the correct function, but outside returns  RESULT Promise{<pending>} . question here: undefined

Comment: Hmm I know theres something simple im missing, this again works from within the callback, but not outside, I guess im not understanding Async. So should I just run everything I need to do from within the callback?

Comment: Thank you sooo much You all made me realize that I need to learn async a little better. Can't tell you how many hours I put into this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are replacing the object reference. You can like this:

```
var quesObj={ result: null };
pushQues(quesObj);
console.log('and quesobj here: '+ quesObj);
console.log('question here: '+ quesObj.result.Ques);
```

The function:

```
var pushQues = function(quesObj){ 
  var query = {AnswerId: 'Texas'};
  Question.findOne(query).lean().exec(function(err,docs){
      console.log(docs.Ques);
      console.log(docs);
      quesObj.result = docs;
  });
};
```

Another option is to use callback:

```
var pushQues = function(callback){ 
  var query = {AnswerId: 'Texas'};
  Question.findOne(query).lean().exec(function(err,docs){
      console.log(docs.Ques);
      console.log(docs);
      callback(err, docs);
  });
};



var quesObj={ result: null };
pushQues(function(err, obj) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('and quesobj here: '+ quesObj);
  console.log('question here: '+ quesObj.Ques);
});
```

Comment: So for the first answer my console was still null and undefined

Comment: The second answer with the call back: console was [object Object] and undefined

Comment: Try to log the object like this: `console.log('and quesobj here: ', quesObj);` with a comma instead of plus sign